# Search Older unanswered and no upvoted questions?

Tags: support, unanswered-questions, search

Do you guys know a good way to search for older unanswered questions with no upvotes? I've already tried this:

[answers:0 is:question closed:0](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=answers:0%20is:question%20closed:0)

but gives the newest first; I want the opposite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't search for "oldest" questions (other than paging to the end of newest), but you can search a date range, for example:

[`answers:0 is:question closed:0 created:2009..2010`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=answers:0%20is:question%20closed:0%20created:2009..2010) would search questions created 2009-2010

Similarly there is a `lastactive:` which is when the question was last modified (edited, answered, etc.), like this:

[`answers:0 is:question closed:0 lastactive:2009..2010`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=answers:0%20is:question%20closed:0%20lastactive:2009..2010)

Both of the above examples are links, click to see the results.

Comment: I guess that's the better approach. Thanks!

Comment: Are there docs for the various keywords of stackoverflow search?

Answer (score 1):

Scroll down to the bottom of that page.  Click on the really big number to the right of all the little numbers (immediately to the left of the "next").

Comment: ahahah I meant the fast "I could bookmark this link" way